# Terminal window does not contain username with only prompt

Tags: command-line

I was sourcing a file to install OpenFOAM after long time also my user name in terminal didn't come up as i have attached a snap shot i can see only prompt.
How to resolve this  ?

Comment: were is the snapshot ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **bash**, try the following command

```
PS1="\u$ "
```

put this in .bashrc file will make it works in all sessions.
If you are using **zsh**, try this:

```
PS1="%n$ "
```

put it into .zshrc file will make it works in al sessions.

Comment: My terminal is blank... I can't execute any commands.. How can i resolve this

Comment: @user250235 Could you provide more information about your problem such as screenshot or the script you sourced?

Comment: First i typed command "gedit .bashrc" then i have changed the source path and later sourced it by "source $HOME/.bashrc" command. After this only command prompt appeared instead of user:~$

Comment: @user250235 I guess you used [this](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi/linux/bks/SGI_EndUser/books/Openfoam_UG/sgi_html/ch02.html) script? In this script you should start setup.sh with parameter SP or DP. It seems that you bash session exits just after you start it. And also make sure you are using correct Shebang. If my guess is wrong, could you provide the instructions you followed? And also I could not find screen shot in you question.

Comment: EITHER
    if running bash or ksh (if in doubt type echo $SHELL), source the etc/bashrc file by adding the following line to the end of your $HOME/.bashrc file:

    source $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.3.0/etc/bashrc
                                                                  then type “source $HOME/.bashrc” in the current terminal window. This is what i followed and i don't know how to Upload a picture here.

Comment: It seems that this script will cost long time to run, your bash may be just under processing. Try removing that source command from your **$HOME/.bashrc** and run it manually.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to get .bashrc file as any of the commands are not executing . How to kill this ?